# Loop and Array format

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm just finishing up this program I had to write for class. The program is supposed to get input from the user for the "ID" and "Day" and my teacher is asking us to put a loop in both those sections in case the user doesn't input the correct ID/Day. I've written the program to where it can take the input, but it won't be able to differentiate if the input is valid or not and will continue through the rest of the program. Also at the end of the array it's supposed to print the array and I've done that. I just would like to put the ID (A, B, C ,D) next to the array. I'd like for the end result to have the ID to the left of the array listed downwards to line up with the 4x5 table. If you guys have any advice/tips on how it could be done it'd be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Salesman
{
 public static void main(String[]args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  char[] names = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
  char[] days = {'M', 'T', 'W', 'H', 'F'};
  double[][] week = new double[4][5];
  int stop = 0;
  char nameInput;
  char dayInput;
  double cost;
  int row;
  int column;

  do
  {
        System.out.println("Enter the salesman ID as A, B, C or D.");
        String nameString = input.nextLine();
        nameInput = nameString.charAt(0);
        row = rowSearch(names, nameInput);

        System.out.println("Enter the day of the week as M, T, W, H, or F");
        String dayString = input.nextLine();
        dayInput = dayString.charAt(0);
        column = columnSearch(days, dayInput);

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of the sale");
        cost = input.nextDouble();
        week[row][column] = cost;

        System.out.println("Is there more data? Enter Y for more or N to stop");
        input.nextLine();
        String dataString = input.nextLine();
        char dataInput = dataString.charAt(0);

        if (dataInput == 'N')
        {
                stop = -1;
        }
        else
        {
                stop = 1;
        }
  }
  while (stop >= 0);

  System.out.println("  M     T     W     H     F");
  for (row = 0; row < week.length; row++)
  {
        for (column = 0; column < week[row].length; column++)
        {
                System.out.printf("$%1.2f ", week[row][column]);
        }
     System.out.println();
  }
 }
 public static int rowSearch(char[] names, char idInput)
 {
        int row = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
                 if (idInput == names[i])
                  row = i;
        }
        return row;
 }
 public static int columnSearch(char[] days, char columnInput)
 {
        int column = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++)
        {
                if (columnInput == days[i])
                  column = i;
        }
        return column;
 }
}
```

Comment: Write one or more methods that asks the user for specified information and validates, but won't return until it's valid or the user enters an exit condition...

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing one or more methods that can prompt a user for some input and that can validate the response themselves.  These methods should continue to loop until a valid response is given (or some exit code is entered).

For example...

```
public String ask(String prompt, char... validResponses) {
    String response = null;
    String testResponses = String.valueOf(validResponses).toLowerCase();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        response = input.nextLine();
    } while (!testResponses.contains(response.toLowerCase()));
    return response;
}
```

Then you can simply call the method with the information you need...

```
 String response = ask("Enter the salesman ID as A, B, C or D.", 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

You would then just use the response as you normally would...

This example uses a single method which takes a prompt and a list of valid characters.  You could as easily write two separate methods which process the individual requests...

```
nameInput = askForSalesMan();
dayInput = askForDay();
```

But that comes down to what you feel you can best handle...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, my professor is specifically wanting us to have that loop in the program.

Comment: Well, you need to translate the concept to you main method then