# User enters what he wants, as well as price and amount

Tags: java, receipt

My program should ask the user for the name, the price as well as the amount of what he wants, until he presses "x". At this point the program should print the receipt.

1. How can I save all the user inputs without knowing how many items he wishes to buy?
2. I am using three classes. I do not know how to give the names, amounts, prices from the Main-class to the class Eintrag.
3. How do I call the list from the Kassenzettel class in the main for me to print?
4. Also, I override the to String method, for my receipt to "supermarket-like", will this formatting be applied in the main class?

here is my main -class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What would you like? ");
        String produkt = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many pieces do you want?");
        int anzahl = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How much does " + produkt + "cost?");
        double preis = scanner.nextDouble();


        //Im not even sure if that should be there
        Kassenzettel list =new Kassenzettel();
        Eintrag carrots = new Eintrag("carrots", 5, 0.40);
        Kassenzettel.add(carrots);



        System.out.println("__________________________________");
        System.out.println("    IHRE RECHNUNG             ");
        System.out.println("__________________________________");


    }
}
```

My Eintrag-class:

```
public class Eintrag {

    private String produkt;
    private double preis;
    private int anzahl;

    public Eintrag(String produkt, int anzahl, double preis) { 
        this.anzahl=anzahl;
        this.produkt=produkt;
        this.preis=preis;   
    }

public int getAnzahl(){
    return this.anzahl;
}
public double getPreis(){
    return this.preis * this.anzahl;
}
public String getProdukt() {
    return this.produkt;
}

public void setAnzahl(int anzahl) {
    this.anzahl = anzahl;
}

public String toString() {
    return (String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR",produkt , anzahl, preis 
                            + "%30.2f EUR", anzahl * preis));


 }
}
```

My Kassenzettel class, which should consist of a list of Eintrag objects
import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Kassenzettel {

private static ArrayList<Eintrag> kassenZettel;
private double summe;

// Constructs a new empty grocery list.
public static void add(Eintrag item) {
    kassenZettel.add(item);

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return (String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR",kassenZettel 
                            + "%30.2f EUR"
                            + "SUMME", summe));

}
}
```

Comment: *"How can I save all the user inputs without knowing how many items he wishes to buy?"* - Either use a `List` of some kind, which can grow dynamically and keep loop until the user enters some exit condition ("Want to buy more stuff?") or ask the user in advance the number of items they want to buy (and only loop that many times)

Comment: *"I am using three classes. I am not sure how to give the names, amounts, prices from the Main-class to the class Eintrag."* - [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: *"Also, I override the to String method, in order for my receipt to "supermarket-like", will this formatting be applied in the main class?"*- So long as who ever is printing it uses the `toString` method (ie `System.out.println(instanceOfKassenzettel)`

Comment: *"How do I call the list from the Kassenzettel class in the main in order for me to print?"* provide a accessor method of some kind, ie `Kassenzettel#getItems` which returns the `List` (or a copy or unmodifiable version of the `List`) - [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: That's a good idea, may you help me with he loop? I don't really know where i'd begin

Comment: *"That's a good idea, may you help me with he loop? "* - something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857820/loop-and-array-format/24857865#24857865) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107751/try-catch-that-will-catch-if-user-input-is-incorrect/32107883#32107883)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, if i got, what you want, but you can use something like this:

change the toString method of Kassenzettel to:

```
double sum = 0;
String ret = "";
for(int i = 0; i< kassenZettel.size(); i++){
  ret += kassenZettel.get(i).toString()+"\r\n";
  sum += kassenZettel.get(i).getPreis();
}
ret += "\r\nSumme: "+sum;
```

The next point, you have to make a loop for user input:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

//create an instance of kassenzettel to add your produkts to
Kassenzettel list =new Kassenzettel();

//set variable to check if read or not (not needed if using break!)
boolean readOn = true;

//loop for reading until user inputs x or X
while(readOn){
  System.out.println("What would you like? ");
  String produkt = scanner.nextLine();

  //check if produkt name is X or x => exit the loop 
  if(produkt.equalsIgnoreCase("x")){
    readOn = false;
    break;
  }
  System.out.println("How many pieces do you want?");
  int anzahl = scanner.nextInt();
  System.out.println("How much does " + produkt + "cost?");
  double preis = scanner.nextDouble();

  //add a new item to kassenzettel
  list.add(new Eintrag(produkt, anzahl, preis));
}

//print the output of kassenzettel
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

**EDIT:**

and remove:

```
    //Im not even sure if that should be there
    Kassenzettel list =new Kassenzettel();
    Eintrag carrots = new Eintrag("carrots", 5, 0.40);
    Kassenzettel.add(carrots);
```

**Working code:**

http://pastebin.com/3acgm5St

Comment: Thanks for your help!
However I'm not getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Kassenzettel.add(Kassenzettel.java:10)
 at Main.main(Main.java:31)"
What am I doing wrong? 
Do I need to modify the entrag class?

Comment: please post the following lines: Main.java line 31 and Kassenzettel.java line 10. (Bitte die genannten zeilen posten, dann sehe ich, was da nicht stimmt, NullPointerException heißt, dass da irgendwas null ist)

Comment: //add a new item to kassenzettel(30-32)
  list.add(new Eintrag(produkt, anzahl, preis));
  }

Comment: //line 9-11
public static void add(Eintrag produkt) {
        kassenZettel.add(produkt);
    }

Comment: remove the keyword static and insert a this. before kassenZettel.add...
here a untested code: http://pastebin.com/9CfFX4si

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, even with your code, I'm not sure why.. Do you have an idea?
Also, what is the return type of the toString()-method of Kassenzettel?It should list all objects of Eintrag as well as the total sum.

Comment: ah, got the error .... you forgot to initialize the array list:
private ArrayList<Eintrag> kassenZettel = new ArrayList<Eintrag>();

**Link:**
http://pastebin.com/eVkMFK4D

Comment: to avoid whitespaces as product name, you should test for them:
(the reading loop got a small change) http://pastebin.com/YPkLMX0k

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
 at Eintrag.toString(Eintrag.java:29)
 at Kassenzettel.toString(Kassenzettel.java:17)
 at Main.main(Main.java:44)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves my questions. Up vote coming up!!
^^Why do I have the above error when I try to print the receipt?
What is wrong with my formatting?

Comment: copy the latest code from me (see link in edited post). That will solve the problem. You try to format with wrong parameters.:
(compare my toString of Eintrag and yours )

Comment: I have and it works just fine, I really appreciate the help.
If you have a minute or two, may you help me out with this code? i can't post on SO anymore
Link: http://pastebin.com/NuLtYEhu

Comment: i will have a look on it

Comment: I am not familiar with javaFX, but i think, your application instance need a methode called init. See following description: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html
Do you have to use JavaFX or can you use plain java?

Comment: I need to use JAVAFX, i'm new to JAVA and i don't know how to create buttons and co without javaFX. Thanks for the help!