# Code to take an input and check if its a valid age, if not repeat until it is

Tags: java, input, methods, do-while

I'm trying to code this program to take input and check if its a valid age between 0 and 150. I'm using do-while to do so but it's not repeating until the condition is true. I can't see where it's going wrong. Maybe I'm not understanding do-while correctly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ValidAge;
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        matches();
    }

    public static void matches()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do
        {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if(input >= 0 && input <= 150)
            {
                System.out.println(input);
                System.out.println("Age is valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(input);
                System.out.println("Age is NOT valid");
            }
        }
        while(input < 0 || input > 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep prompting for the correct user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023186/how-to-keep-prompting-for-the-correct-user-input-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the input with a value before entering the 'do while'.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ValidAge{// Change here
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        matches();
    }
    public static void matches()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;// Change here
        do
        {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if(input >= 0 && input <= 150)
            {
                System.out.println(input);
                System.out.println("Age is valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(input);
                System.out.println("Age is NOT valid");// Change here
            }
        }
        while(input > 0 && input < 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok, but why is that?  is it not ok for a variable to be defined within a loop?

Comment: Is this really the answer? The code in the while loop isn't checking for values in between 0 and 150, it is checking for values less than 0, and above 150

Comment: @javabeginner if you are looking to check for values in between, refer to my solution.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to correct the code logic. As for the loop, I believe it is a java constraint. See this link: https://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-while-loop

Comment: @javabeginner If you declare the variable inside the loop then it's scope is inside the loop, i.e. it can't be accessed outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ValidAge{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        matches();
    }
    public static void matches()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;
        do
        {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if(input >= 0 && input <= 150)
            {
                System.out.println(input);
                System.out.println("Age is valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(input);
                System.out.println("Age is NOT valid");// Change here
            }
        }
        while(input >= 0 && input <= 150);
    }
}
```

The difference is if you want to check between 0 and 150, you have to check if its greater than 0 AND if it is less than 150. This would check if input was in between. What you were checking if it was either or, which is not the correct logic.

Comment: You are correct, I meant including those numbers. I was checking if the number was above 0 or below 150 those numbers included because it doesn't have to be both at the same time for it to be a false statement. I hope this clears it up.

Comment: hm, mine is checking above 0 and below 150 isn't it? To make it inclusive you can do >= instead of just >